# negative length vectors are not allowed while applying operation on a huge matrix

Tags: r, memory, sparse-matrix

I have a matrix M1 ( 3644069845 elements , 27.2 Gb )

```
dim(M1)
[1]   5785 629917
```

Any operation on this matrix that involves parsing through the elements is ending up with the error
Few eg :

```
SM1<-as(M1,"dgCMatrix")
Error in .Call(dense_to_Csparse, from) : 
  negative length vectors are not allowed
```

Note that my system has 240 GB ram ( ubuntu16 , r4.8xlarge ) and i am constantly monitoring it to see if RAM is getting exhausted , but it seems RAM is still fine.
If I can make it to a sparse matrix , then I could reduce the size upto 3 Gb , because majority elements are zeros ( 95 % are zeroes ).

Any suggestions to make it a sparse matrix would be helpful.

The suggestion on the below post
[R - data frame - convert to sparse matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27008633/r-data-frame-convert-to-sparse-matrix)

sparsify , does not work. After 4 hours I stopped the execution.

Comment: How do you create this matrix?

Comment: by loading a DAT file into a data.frame and then converting into matrix

Comment: I would parse the file and create a sparse matrix from the beginning. However, you probably should use a tool other than R to make that efficient.

Comment: It is about the vector length limit (````.Machine$integer.max````, 2^31)? Matrix is stored as vector internally. Is it possible that ````dense_to_Csparse```` (probably in C) does not allow anything longer than 2^31?

Answer (score 2):

You could split up your matrix M1 so that it doesn't exceed the vector length limit (2^31) when making it sparse, then make the splitted matrices sparse and combine them again:

```
# Split
m11 <- M1[,0:314958]
m12 <- M1[,314959:nrow(M1)]

# Sparse
m11_sparse <- Matrix(as.matrix(m11), sparse = TRUE)
m12_sparse <- Matrix(as.matrix(m12), sparse = TRUE)

# Combine
M1_sparse <- cbind(m11_sparse,m12_sparse)

# Clean
rm(M1,m11,m12,m11_sparse,m12_sparse)
gc()
```