# how to cast a tibble to a sparse matrix

Tags: r, dplyr, sparse-matrix, purrr

Consider this simple tibble

```
> data_frame(col1 = c(1,2,3), col2 = c(3,2,NA))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
   col1  col2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     3
2     2     2
3     3    NA
```

What is the most efficient way to cast it as a sparse matrix?
I tried something like

```
> data_frame(col1 = c(1,2,3), col2 = c(3,2,NA)) %>% 
+   as(., 'sparseMatrix')
Error in as(from, "CsparseMatrix") : 
  no method or default for coercing “tbl_df” to “CsparseMatrix”
```

with no success. Trying as suggested:

```
y <- purrr::reduce(cbind2, map(df, 'Matrix', sparse = TRUE))
```

does not work either.

Any good ideas using the tidyverse?
Thanks!

Comment: maybe useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27008633/r-data-frame-convert-to-sparse-matrix

Comment: I saw it, but I need a tidyverse solution. no `lapply`

Comment: You can adapt the `lapply`/`Reduce` answer to instead use `purrr::map`/`purrr::reduce`. I have very little experience with sparse matrices, so I'm not sure if what I got is what you're looking for. Maybe post an example of the result?

Comment: thanks but were you able to make it work with `map` and `reduce`?

Comment: @camille I tried, but without success. see edited

Comment: `map(df, Matrix::Matrix, sparse = T) %>% reduce(cbind2)` gets me a 2-column sparse matrix. Like I said, I don't know much about sparse matrices and I'm not sure what you're after for a result. Why do you have `'Matrix'` in quotes? And where are you loading it from?

Comment: hey @camille that works pretty well! can you post that as a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a translation of [the bounty-awarded answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27062757/5325862) to the post linked above, from base `lapply`/`Reduce` to `purrr`'s `map`/`reduce`. The previous answer used:

```
Reduce(cbind2, lapply(x[,-1], Matrix, sparse = TRUE))
```

Part of how this works is that data frames are technically lists, so you can use `map` to iterate over the columns of the data frame. This yields two sparse matrices, one for each column:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- data_frame(col1 = c(1,2,3), col2 = c(3,2,NA))

map(df, Matrix::Matrix, sparse = T)
#> $col1
#> 3 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#>       
#> [1,] 1
#> [2,] 2
#> [3,] 3
#> 
#> $col2
#> 3 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#>        
#> [1,]  3
#> [2,]  2
#> [3,] NA
```

If you then reduce it with `cbind2`, that gets you a single sparse matrix.

```r
map(df, Matrix::Matrix, sparse = T) %>% 
  reduce(cbind2)
#> 3 x 2 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#>          
#> [1,] 1  3
#> [2,] 2  2
#> [3,] 3 NA
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: hey camille, merci beaucoup! :) I see you write `javascript` as well. Any good book to recommend? I just wanna add some cool effects to my website, and parse SVG charts :)