# Convert large R data frame to dgcmatrix

Tags: r, dataframe, sparse-matrix

I am trying to convert a large data frame to `dgcmatrix` in R. But failing with unreasonable memory requirements.

```
library(Matrix)
dim(my_df)
[1]  22865 442010
# Convert to regular matrix
my.M <- as.matrix(my_df)

class(my.M)
[1] "matrix"
```

for simulating the similar matrix (the row names and column names are important to keep)[updated based on the comment, Warning: need ~80GM RAM space]

```
my.M <- replicate(n = 442010, expr = abs(rnorm(n = 22865, mean = 0, sd = 1)))
#object.size(my.M)
#80852469416 bytes
colnames(my.M) <- c(paste("IncidentBarcode_XXXX",seq(1:ncol(my.M)),sep=""))
rownames(my.M) <- c(paste("group",seq(1:nrow(my.M)),sep=""))
```

```
sparse.M <- Matrix(my.M, sparse = T )
Error in (if (is.logical(from)) .m2lgC else .m2dgC)(from) : 
  'Realloc' could not re-allocate memory (18446744072179369984 bytes)
```

```
dgc.Matrix <- as(my.M, "dgCMatrix")
Error in asMethod(object) : 
  'Realloc' could not re-allocate memory (18446744072179369984 bytes)
```

I have also tried previous methods (as @priya mentioned in comments)

```
dgr.Matrix <- as(my.M, "dgRMatrix") 

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x7ed8fe848868, cause 'memory not mapped'
```

```
matSparse <- sparseMatrix(
+   i = rownames(my_df), 
+   j = colnames(my_df), 
+   dims = c(nrow(my_df), ncol(my_df)), 
+   dimnames = list(rownames(my_df),  colnames(my_df))
+ )
Error in i + !(m.i || i1) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Comment: this data frame have lots of columns. Are they dummies generated by model.matrix() aka one-hot encoding?

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of column as the downstream analysis package needs in that format. Its not generated by model.matrix()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R convert matrix or data frame to sparseMatrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555210/r-convert-matrix-or-data-frame-to-sparsematrix)

Comment: I have already tried that answer and did not work. I will update the question with the error I got in a while

Comment: try: `s<-which(my.M!=0);sparseMatrix(i = s[,1],j = s[,2], x = my.M[s])`

Comment: that give `Error in s[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions
`

Comment: You should never create a dense matrix if a sparse matrix is your goal. Please provide a (simulated) example of your data.frame. (Also, in `sparseMatrix`, `i` and `j` are numeric indices. You can't pass them row and column names, resp.)

Comment: @Roland I update the question by adding the matrix simulation

Comment: Your example matrix isn't sparse

Comment: If you turn an actually dense matrix (a matrix not containing mostly zeros) into a sparse matrix data structure, you actually need more memory (possibly three times as much memory) than with a dense matrix data structure.

Comment: @Roland This makes sense. I am going to convert all the value <1 to zero and give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to split the large dataframe by rows/cols, convert to dgcMatrix and then join them.

```
nsplit = 10
splitMxList = lapply(split(my.M, cut(1:nrow(my.M), nsplit)), function(mx) {
    Matrix(as.matrix(mx), sparse=T)
})
sparse.M = Reduce(rbind, splitMxList)
```